# google app engine not found problem

Tags: google-app-engine

I am really really new to java and google app engine also. I read google's tutorial and did sample guestbook application of google. It seems to work correctly. And i did deploy it as well. However, I have problem to reach my http://example.appspot.com/ My application id is example. And i made changes in my xml files. But still it keeps saying '404 Error Not Found' I dont think i did anything wrong though. In logs it says No handlers matched this URL. Could you help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You have to create a project on appspot.com first. Example.appspot.com is not your project and it's just a demo URL provided by google. I doubt you can deploy your guestbook using "example" as the app-id.